# JavaFX ScrollPane setFitToHeight

Tags: javafx, resize, scrollpane

since the `ListView` seems to have some visual bugs when it comes to storing items with a different cell size (resulted in duplicated entries @displaying), I decided to try out a `ScrollPane`. I replaced the `ListView` with a `ScrollPane` with a inner `VBox` (there are custom `HBox` stored). So long it's working fine, I dont get any visual bugs any more. 
Now I just have a simple problem: As soon the `ScrollPane` is "full" and starts scrolling, it seems to adjust the size of my "bigger" items.

Here a screen how it looks before the resizing:

[image: before resize]

Here a screen how it looks when the resize starts:

[image: image at resize start]

Here is the fxml of my custom `HBox`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>


<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.HBox" fx:id="hboxGridContainer" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" prefWidth="580.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" styleClass="theme-presets inbox-entry">
  <children>
      <GridPane fx:id="gridPaneMessages" prefWidth="350.0">
          <columnConstraints>
              <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="true" hgrow="ALWAYS" />
              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          </columnConstraints>
          <rowConstraints>
              <RowConstraints fillHeight="true" vgrow="ALWAYS" />

          </rowConstraints>
          <children>
          <HBox fx:id="hboxMessage" alignment="TOP_LEFT" maxHeight="Infinity" minWidth="191.0">
             <children>
                    <Label fx:id="labelMessage" alignment="TOP_LEFT" maxHeight="Infinity" minWidth="191.0" text="blablubkeks" wrapText="true" />
             </children>
          </HBox>
              <AnchorPane GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                  <children>
                      <ImageView fx:id="imageViewEncrypted" fitHeight="33.0" fitWidth="33.0" layoutX="43.0" layoutY="-2.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                          <image>
                              <Image url="@../../images/key.png" />
                          </image>
                      </ImageView>
                      <ImageView fx:id="imageViewSigned" fitHeight="42.0" fitWidth="33.0" layoutX="80.0" layoutY="-2.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                          <image>
                              <Image url="@../../images/doublecheck.png" />
                          </image>
                      </ImageView>
                      <Label fx:id="labelTime" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="76.0" text="Label" />
                  </children>
              </AnchorPane>
          </children>
      </GridPane>
  </children>
</fx:root>
```

Here is an extract of my `ScrollPane` usage in fxml:

```xml
<ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPaneChat" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0">
   <content>

       <VBox fx:id="chatWindowListView" prefHeight="531.0" prefWidth="607.0" />
     </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

The official documentation states, the `ScrollPane` `fitToHeight` Property is default on `false`, which should prevent resizing my `HBox`'s. I want the `HBox` to stay at it's original height.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried to set `minHeight()` and `maxHeight()`? If you set all values to one size, no resizing should happen.

Comment: If I set these values hardcoded, the HBox doesn't get resized and the size stays for all elements the same. The problem is, I need the HBox to grow vertically when the message is very long.. That's why I can't hardcode these values.

Comment: The problem is, that if the scrollbars will be shown, they need space. So they asked the inner vbox to shrink in size. And as you said in your custom HBox `maxWidth=Infinity` and `maxHeight=Infinity`, it will resize. So you need to stop growing and shrinking by setting absolute values if you want to have even sized rows. PrefWidth and Height is only a "want" to, and min and maxWidth is a "have to".